# Initialize a 2D Array of JButton reference type

Tags: java, arrays, swing, multidimensional-array

How to initialize/declare a 2D array of reference type in Java? In particular I want to initialize a 2d array of JButton type (3x3) and then add them to a frame inside the constructor. How do i go about it?

Comment: JButton[][] buttons = JButton[3][3]; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MadProgrammer is correct, but in order to use them, you will need to initialize every JButton individually thereafter.

```
JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][3];
for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
    for(int x = 0; x <= 2; x++){
        buttons[i][x] = new JButton();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be better to use < buttons.length and < buttons[i].length

Comment: Yep, as @MadProgrammer suggests, this will avoid magic numbers and improve safety.

Comment: I was getting error for writing in the loop - 
JButton buttons[i][x] = new JButton();

Comment: What error are you getting? It should not be JButton buttons[i][x], it should be buttons[i][x] = new JButton()

Comment: yes I'm just saying why i got the error earlier. Thanks to you its now resolved. (y)

Answer (score 1):

```
JButton[][] myButtons = JButton[3][3];
```

creates the array you need. It declares and initializes the array. If you want to declare and initialize it separately, then you can do it this way:

```
JButton[][] myButtons;
//...
myButtons = JButton[3][3];
```

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for the observation, fixed.